# Migrating from HTTP to HTTPClient on Angular8

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

I'm migrating my Angular to use the new HttpClient but I'm having some problems to achieve the same result I was getting with Http..

I'm gonna put **on comments** what I have tried:

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http, Header } from '@angular/http';
//import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Environment } from '../app.component';
//all other component imports

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService implements OnDestroy {
    private url = Environment.origin;
    private headers = new Headers({
    //private headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/cp+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    //constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    buscarEmpresas(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/${pesquisa}/search`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));
    }
    /* return this.http.get<any>(`${ this.url }/companies/${ pesquisa }/search`, { headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' } )
     *       .pipe(map(res => res ));
     * -- also tried to stop on headers -- return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${ this.url }/companies/${ pesquisa }/search`, { headers: this.headers }*/

    getEmpresaByUrlLink(urlLink: string): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }
    /*  return this.http.get<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
     *      .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response)));*/
```

When making these changes, the first method returns nothing and the second returns 500.

Comment: with httpClient you need'nt add Headers (by defect is json) nor use response.json() (the response is yet a json. Well, if your API return a string (it's no normal) you need use `{response:text}`, see https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data, but I tell you that, in my experience, is not normal that you need make this.

Comment: Thanks Eliseo!! I tried to remove the header from the options and it didn't work. I also tried to remove the `.pipe (map ((response) => response.json ().response))` and it didn't work :(

Comment: check what do you received using `console.log(response)` in subscribe function. if you received some like 'res:{....}` you can map `map((response)=>response.res)`.

Comment: For the first method, console.log returned `response: Array(10)` and it worked even excluding options (as you said) and including `.pipe (map ((response) => response.response)` \o/ . I didn't quite understand why, but it worked.
The second method (which returns an object), if I remove the header, the browser complains. And it stills return 500